# MySQL - Sort and limit by table string

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql tables. One table with strings, for example abc, def, ghi, jkl. The other table contains info about the strings in the other table, for example 'Three first letters in the alphabet', '3-6 letters in the alphabet', and so on. There can be multiple (around 25 rows) for each string in this table.

I want to return 3 rows from the second table for each string in the first one, for example:

```
table1.string | table2.info
---------------------------
abc           | blahblah
abc           | blahblah2
def           | blahblah
abc           | blahblah3
def           | blahblah2
def           | blahblah3
```

I can get the strings from table1 first, the do a foreach and execute even more queries to get limit 3 from the table2. But that does not seem to be good for the performance.

How would a query like this look like?

Comment: Can you post the create table SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it works in MySQL, but in MSSQL this would be

```
SELECT
    table1.string,
    table2.info
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.stringID = table1.ID
WHERE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY table1.string ORDER BY table2.info) <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (it's not very fast though):

```
SELECT string,info FROM
(
  select t1.string, t2.info, 
  @n_rec := IF(@tmp!=t1.string,1,@n_rec+1) as nrec, 
  @tmp := t1.string
  FROM 
  table_1 t1
  INNER JOIN  table_2 t2 ON t2.table_1_id = t1.id 
  order by t1.string
 )yy
 INNER JOIN (SELECT @n_rec := 0) X
 INNER JOIN (SELECT @tmp:= null)Y  
 WHERE nrec <=3;
```

You might want to use `LEFT JOIN table_2` instead of `INNER JOIN table_2` if you need to include records from table_1 with no info in table_2.